# DocuSign Dynamics integration - can't enable entities

Tags: dynamics-crm, docusignapi

I use Microsoft Dynamics CRM 365 and the DocuSign Integration for Dynamics 365 version 5.
My problem is that I can't enable any entities in the DocuSign Admin page in Dynamics.
When I save and refresh the page the previous chosen entities are not selected.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compared an other Dynamics demo org and figured out the reason for the issue.
Found the required info in the plugin trace logs.
My Dynamics org was created with the base language german.

The DocuSign integration needs checks if the user has a role with name "system administrator" and in my case the name of system admin role is in german.
And the langue package english should be installed on your Dynamics org.

After that I could enable the entities on the DocuSig Admin page.